# Apache - Redirect "URL folder" that starts with.... to specific real directory

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, virtualhost

I'm looking for redirect an URL that starts with the same substring to a specific directory.
I'm working with apache, trying to do it in `.conf` file to avoid create any empty real subdirectory.

For e.g.:

https://example.com/foobar
https://example.com/foolol
https://example.com/foosub
https://example.com/footel

redirects to:

https://example.com/foo (real directory)

**How can achieve this with a configuration in apache .conf file?**

Please comment if you need more information about this, glad to update my answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't downvote but please show what you've tried.

Comment: @anubhava thanks for comment. I don't even know how to start, when I search in google I can't found any relative thing about this, only redirection but not partial or substring prommatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Apache conf file you may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?foo\w+/?$ /foo/ [L,NC]
```

**Details:**

- `^/?foo\w+/?$` Matches `/foo` followed by 1+ word characters and an optional `/`
- `/foo/` is what we're using to rewrite it.
- Flag `L` is for `Last` and `NC` is for *no case*

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: Nice!!! I was looking the details in google about L and NC. Didn't know about regex in this case. Thanks a lot for your time!!! Is hard some cases search in a language that is not your native like my case.

Comment: Most welcome. I have added couple of reference links.